# Do changes revert when an Extrinsic errors?

Tags: pallet, extrinsic

I have an Extrinsic which modifies some storage variables and then returns either `Err` or `Ok`.
Will it revert the changes when I return `Err`?
How can I make sure that it only commits to changes when I return `Ok`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: All storage changes are now reverted when an error from a call is returned. This makes writing code much easier.

**Original answer**:
Currently you need to make sure to **never return an error after you modified storage**.
In your case you need to do all checks that can error before modifying something.
Returning `Err` after a modification will most likely put your pallet in an undefined state.

This is not the most ergonomic and will gladly change in the future.
An annotation à la `#[storage_layer]` or something similar will be added.
This would allow to write code more easily as it would revert all changes upon error.

Will update this post once its done.

Comment: In the case that something that could return an Err is done after modifying state , even after doing preliminary checks is it okay to handle that with a ".expect()"? I know the runtime shouldn't panic, but the behaviour shouldn't occur since the checks have already been made, yet I'm a bit paranoid around the Result type I get back at that point.

Comment: @islami00 will be answered here https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/317/when-to-use-expect

Answer (score 1):

Extrinsic marked as `#[transactional]` will get discarded if it returns `Err`.

But there're some issues about `transactional` annotation, see [paritytech/substrate#10806](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/10806)

Comment: Yes right! The whole issue with discarded state will be solved when `#[transactional]` becomes the default for Substrate. Then it will be as simple as in Solidity.